# Remove duplicates from output

Tags: terraform

I have the following output:

```
output "regions_data" {
value = regions({
for region, data in var.regions :
regions => "${region}/${data.postcode}"
})
}
```

Which contains duplicates like(it is intentional):

```
regions = {
   reg1 = {
        postcode = "1"
},
   reg1 = {
        postcode = "1"
},
   reg2 = {
        postcode = "2"
}
}
```

How can I remove the duplicates from the output?

Comment: what is the value of `var.regions`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not comply to the basic rules of maps or objects. Nor there is any `regions` function you use in the code. The provided code is not a proper Terraform syntax.

I believe however, you might have meant the following example:

```
variable "regions" {
  default = {
    reg1 = [
      {
        postcode = 1
        area     = "oak-county"
      },
      {
        postcode = 2
        area     = "birch-county"
      }
    ],
    reg2 = [
      {
        postcode = 1
        area     = "fir-county"
      },
      {
        postcode = 2
        area     = "pine-county"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

In a case, when the two maps have the same keys, you can use flatten to break up everything to pieces, then rejoin everything back together:

```
locals {
  flatten = flatten([
    for region_key, region in var.regions : [
      for area in region :
      {
        key   = "${region_key}-${area.postcode}"
        value = area.area
      }
    ]
  ])
}

output "flattened_regions" {
  value = local.flatten
}

output "remap" {
  value = { for key, data in local.flatten :
    data.key => data.value
  }
}
```

Even if the code above doesn't exactly fit your case, please experiment in a similar manner - or, provide more complete example of variables you have and the outcome you need.

Source: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten

Answer (score 1):

### Probably what you want

I have no idea what you've meant by `regions` in `value = regions({` but I assume that this code will do what you want:

```
locals {
  regions = {
    reg1 = {
      postcode = "1"
    },
    reg1 = {
      postcode = "1"
    },
    reg2 = {
      postcode = "2"
    }
  }
}

output "regions_data" {
  value = {
  for region, data in local.regions :
  region => "${region}/${data.postcode}"
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that I replaced `var` with `local` to have one file.
And output of such is:

```
regions_data = {
  "reg1" = "reg1/1"
  "reg2" = "reg2/2"
}
```

Thought be warned that it will use one of keys. It doesn't check for duplicates. It just takes first one.

### But why you shouldn't want it

This solution is quite bad for multiple reasons:

1. You provide variables - why the heck would you put duplicates? :)
2. As I said this merge will not necessarily provide the output you what
3. If var is provided by some terraform code (e.g. this regions_data is in module) then logic of merging should be done outside of module and probably terraform's own [merge](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) would be the answer.